# Why isn't delete and edit working on table using Ajax Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been searching and found some code wich I have changed the connection and vars of the db. Now with these changes I can only add rows in the db. Both delete and edit aren't working, and I don't understand why, because there are no errors.

**Index.php**

```
<html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Live Table Data Edit</title>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <div class="container">  
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <h3 align="center">Table</h3><br />  
                 <div id="live_data"></div>                 
            </div>  
       </div>  
  </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      function fetch_data()  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"select.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#live_data').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  }  
  fetch_data();  
  $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){  
       var nome = $('#nome').text();  
       var preco = $('#preco').text();  
       if(nome == '')  
       {  
            alert("Enter Nome");  
            return false;  
       }  
       if(preco == '')  
       {  
            alert("Enter Preco");  
            return false;  
       }  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"insert.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{nome:nome, preco:preco},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
                 alert(data);  
                 fetch_data();  
            }  
       })  
  });  
  function edit_data(ref, text, column_name)  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"edit.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data){  
                 alert(data);  
            }  
       });  
  }  
  $(document).on('blur', '.nome', function(){  
       var ref = $(this).data("ref1");  
       var nome = $(this).text();  
       edit_data(ref, nome, "nome");  
  });  
  $(document).on('blur', '.preco', function(){  
       var ref = $(this).data("ref2");  
       var preco = $(this).text();  
       edit_data(ref,preco, "preco");  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  
       var ref=$(this).data("ref3");  
       if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"delete.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{id:id},  
                 dataType:"text",  
                 success:function(data){  
                      alert(data);  
                      fetch_data();  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });  
 });  
 </script>
```

**Select.php** (here I creat the table and make it editable)

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crc");  
 $output = '';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM perfumesh ORDER BY ref ASC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 $output .= '  
  <div class="table-responsive">  
       <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                 <th width="10%">REF</th>  
                 <th width="40%">Nome</th>  
                 <th width="40%">Preco</th>  
                 <th width="10%">Delete</th>  
            </tr>';  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td>'.$row["ref"].'</td>  
                 <td class="nome" data-ref1="'.$row["ref"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["nome"].'</td>  
                 <td class="preco" data-ref2="'.$row["ref"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["preco"].'</td>  
                 <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-ref3="'.$row["ref"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
            </tr>  
       ';  
  }  
  $output .= '  
       <tr>  
            <td></td>  
            <td id="nome" contenteditable></td>  
            <td id="preco" contenteditable></td>  
            <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
       </tr>  
  ';  
 }  
 else  
 {  
  $output .= '<tr>  
                      <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
                 </tr>';  
 }  
 $output .= '</table>  
  </div>';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

**Edit.php**

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crc");  
 $ref = $_POST["ref"];  
 $text = $_POST["text"];  
 $column_name = $_POST["column_name"];  
 $sql = "UPDATE perfumesh SET ".$column_name."='".$text."' WHERE ref='".$ref."'";  
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
 {  
      echo 'Data Updated';  
 }  
 ?>
```

**Delete.php**

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crc");  
 $sql = "DELETE FROM perfumesh WHERE ref = '".$_POST["ref"]."'";  
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
 {  
      echo 'Data Deleted';  
 }  
 ?>
```

Original code: http://webslesson.blogspot.pt/2016/02/live-table-add-edit-delete-using-ajax-jquery-in-php-mysql.html

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: You send wrong variable to php change `var ref=$(this).data("ref3");` to `var id=$(this).data("ref3");`  in btn_delete function

Comment: There are a bazillion other things here, variable name mismatches, you're not identifying the proper item in the POST array, etc. etc.

Comment: So you mean all my variables are incorrect?